# Conditionally initialize a struct field - only if it exists in that struct

Tags: c++, api, unit-testing, reflection, initialization

Working on something like a unit testing framework for a very simple API:

```
extern "C" void execute_command(int cmd, void *params);
```

Which casts the `params` to the appropriate struct based on the `cmd` argument. I can't change that interface, nor can I modify the header which specifies the commands and the different param structures (which are all POD).

I do have access to an array of something like:

```
{ 0 /*cmd number*/, "PARAM_STRUCT_FOR_CMD_0", sizeof(PARAM_STRUCT_FOR_CMD_0) }
```

These param structs have some common properties. For example, many of them have a field like `void *pObject;`, though it is not always the same offset. To illustrate, suppose there are three structures:

```
struct {
    void *pObject;
    int someData;
} PARAM_STRUCT_FOR_CMD_0;
struct {
    float someFloatData;
    void *pObject;
} PARAM_STRUCT_FOR_CMD_1;
struct {
    float someFloatData;
    void *pAnotherObject;
} PARAM_STRUCT_FOR_CMD_2;
```

These two `pObject` fields represent the same thing, while `pAnotherObject` is unrelated.

Now, on to what I actually want: I'd like to cast a `void*` to some struct, based on `cmd`, and set its `pObject` field, if it exists in that struct. Ideally, I'd be able to do something like:

```
void *pGlobalObject;
void execcmd(int cmd)
{
    static uint8_t params[MAX_SIZE_OF_PARAM_STRUCT];

    memset(params, 0, MAX_SIZE_OF_PARAM_STRUCT);
    INIT_STRUCT_IF_POSSIBLE(cmd, (void*)params);
    execute_command(cmd, params);
}
```

Where `INIT_STRUCT_IF_POSSIBLE` could be something like:

```
#define INIT_STRUCT_IF_POSSIBLE(cmd, str) \
do {  \
    switch (cmd)  \
    {  \
        case 0: static_cast<PARAM_STRUCT_FOR_CMD_0*>(str)->pObject = pGlobalObject; break;  \
        case 1: static_cast<PARAM_STRUCT_FOR_CMD_1*>(str)->pObject = pGlobalObject; break;  \
        case 2: /* nothing, no pObject field */ break;  \
    }  \
} while (0)
```

except that isn't really scalable. I have ~1000 possible commands, and let's say 5 fields which I'd like to set (no struct has all 5), and new commands can be added, so I'd like to avoid manually changing this.

The obvious solution is an extra build step that parses all the structs, and creates their initializers. Adding this extra build step is a lot of pain though, due to how the project is structured, so I'm hoping for a pure C++ solution.

If there's a way to generate the initializers using the C preprocessor, I'm all for it. If it can somehow be done using templates, just as good. I have boost and C++11 available, if it helps.

One thing that would solve this is the designated initializers, such as `STR x = {.pObject = pGlobalObject; };`. Unfortunately, they cause an error when the field is not available. Any way to just ignore nonexistent fields? (Yes, I know they are C only, not C++, but I can switch to C if needed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the world of SFINAE

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
   std::is_same<decltype(T::pObject), void*>::value
>::type setPobject(T *t) {
   t->pObject = pGlobalObject;
}

void setPobject(void *t) { }

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
   std::is_same<decltype(T::someFloatData), float>::value
>::type setSomeFloatData(T *t) {
   t->someFloatData = someGlobalFloat;
}

void setSomeFloatData(void *t) { }

// ...
```

Just call them for all your objects with the correct types and they will figure out whether they apply or not themselfs. You can also automate the casting

```
template<typename D>
struct Call {
    static void call(void *t) {
       setPobject(static_cast<D*>(t));
       setSomeFloatData(static_cast<D*>(t));
    }
};

// desginated initializers here for convenience (non-C++)
void (* const table[])(void*) = {
   [0] = Call<PARAM_STRUCT_FOR_CMD_0>::call,
   [1] = Call<PARAM_STRUCT_FOR_CMD_1>::call
   // ...
};
```

Comment: very elegant solution.

Comment: Amazing, and very clean. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

With some SFINAE you can detect the member and (type) dispatch assignment accordingly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// Member variable detection
// =========================

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct has_pObject : std::false_type { };

template<typename T>
struct has_pObject<T, decltype(std::declval<T>().pObject, void())> : std::true_type { };

// Optional member variable assignment
// ===================================

namespace Detail
{
    template <typename T>
    void assign_pObject(T& object, void* p, std::false_type) {}

    template <typename T>
    void assign_pObject(T& object, void* p, std::true_type) {
        object.pObject = p;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void assign_pObject(T& object, void* p) {
    Detail::assign_pObject(object, p, has_pObject<T>());
}

// Test
// ====

struct {
    void *pObject = nullptr;
    int someData = 0;
} PARAM_STRUCT_FOR_CMD_0;

struct {
    float someFloatData = 0;
    void *pObject = nullptr;
} PARAM_STRUCT_FOR_CMD_1;

struct {
    float someFloatData = 0;
    void *pAnotherObject = nullptr;
} PARAM_STRUCT_FOR_CMD_2;

int main()
{
    int object;
    assign_pObject(PARAM_STRUCT_FOR_CMD_0, &object);
    assign_pObject(PARAM_STRUCT_FOR_CMD_1, &object);
    assign_pObject(PARAM_STRUCT_FOR_CMD_2, &object);
    std::cout << PARAM_STRUCT_FOR_CMD_0.pObject << '\n';
    std::cout << PARAM_STRUCT_FOR_CMD_1.pObject << '\n';
    std::cout << PARAM_STRUCT_FOR_CMD_2.pAnotherObject << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice, I had no idea how to do that. Learned a lot. Think I'll eventually go with the other answer, but this was very valuable. Thanks.